# What does "shrink someone down" mean?

Tags: meaning

> "I was the First Lady of the United States of America—a job that’s not
>   officially a job, but that nonetheless has given me a platform like
>   nothing I could have imagined. It challenged me and humbled me, lifted
>   me up and ***shrank*** me ***down***, sometimes all at once."
>
> BECOMING, by Michelle Obama

I couldn't find any reference on the web for "Shrinking someone down" What does it mean here? Is it an  idiom?

Comment: Compare to "lifted me up".  And compare to the first half of the sentence.

Comment: @HotLicks, Does 'lift one up' means "to make one feel more confident"?\

Comment: To "lift one up" generally implies making one more inspired and energized.

Answer (score 2):

Shrank me down is in contrast to lift me up. They had the opposite effects on her at the same time. The experience caused her to feel smaller and smaller or less important in comparison to the history going on around her. At the same time she is feeling lifted up or enlarged, more important rather than less because she is indeed a part of the history.

To shrink someone down is to cause them to *feel* as though they were becoming tiny. The Grand Canyon will do this for you. Being badly embarrassed by your mistake can also do it.

Answer (score 1):

For the phrase “shrink down to size” see https://ludwig.guru/s/shrinking+down+to+size

“It shrank me down to size” means that “it” made me realize I’m not as great/important/accomplished as I thought I was.

“Shrank me down” means something similar here; shrinking someone else down [to size] is not as common.  As @hotlicks points out, the use here contrasts with “lifted me up.”  She’s talking about being First Lady.